# Why cannot I grant privilege to a user in pluggable database with SYS user in the root?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, database-administration

I want to grant a privilege to a user in the container database when I'm connected to the container with SYS user. But it says user does not exist.

Besides, there are SYS users in both CDB and PDB. Why there are in each database and what are the differences of each SYS user?

Answer (score 3):

There's a few options.

Connect to sys

```
SQL>conn sys/oracle@//localhost:1521/orcl as sysdba
Connected.
```

Try to grant failed in to my user in the PDB named "xe"

```
SQL> grant dba to klrice container=XE;

Error starting at line : 1 in command -
grant dba to klrice container=XE
Error report -
ORA-65013: invalid CONTAINER clause
65013. 00000 -  "invalid CONTAINER clause"
*Cause:    An invalid CONTAINER clause was encountered.
*Action:   Reissue the DDL statement with a valid CONTAINER clause.
```

Try to grant failed in to my user in ALL PDBs

```
SQL> grant dba to klrice container=ALL;

Error starting at line : 1 in command -
grant dba to klrice container=ALL
Error report -
ORA-01917: user or role 'KLRICE' does not exist
01917. 00000 -  "user or role '%s' does not exist"
*Cause:    There is not a user or role by that name.
*Action:   Re-specify the name.
```

Fails due to "klrice" not being a common user. IF klrice was common, the above would have worked from the CDB.

```
SQL> select username,common from all_users where username = 'KLRICE';

no rows selected
```

Alter session into the PDB to issue the grant and everything works as expected

```
SQL> alter session set container = XE;

Session altered.

SQL> grant dba to klrice;

Grant succeeded.
```